# Red underlines in Visual Studio Code

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I have these red sguiggles:

[image]

I am creating the variables underlined, like this:

```
import SearchFilterViewModel = SearchFilter.SearchFilterViewModel;
import SearchResultsViewModel = SearchResults.SearchResultsViewModel;
import AddProductViewModel = AddProduct.AddProductViewModel;
import Validator = Validation.Validator;

module Bindings {
    export class Binder {
        constructor() {
            searchFilterViewModel = new SearchFilterViewModel();
            searchFilterViewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(searchFilterViewModel);
            searchResultsViewModel = new SearchResultsViewModel();
            addProductViewModel = new AddProductViewModel();
            ko.applyBindings(searchFilterViewModel, $("#search-filter-page")[0]);
            ko.applyBindings(searchResultsViewModel, $("#search-results-page")[0]);
            ko.applyBindings(addProductViewModel, $("#add-product-page")[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

then:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //apply bindings
    var binder = new Binder();
}
```

So the code compiles fine and works. How do I get rid of those red underlines?

Comment: did you check this link:https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/colorizer and you can install visual studio code extension for php like this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Kasik96.format-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare the properties (public by default) :

```
module Bindings {
    export class Binder {
        searchFilterViewModel:SearchFilterViewModel;
        constructor() {
            this.searchFilterViewModel = new SearchFilterViewModel();
```

Answer (score 1):

> So the code compiles fine and works.

Just because the code produces valid JavaScript *doesn't mean there are no compile errors*.

You will most likely see errors if you run the project through `tsc`

More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html